# Multi-line options with the `\usepackage` command

Tags: packages, best-practices, preamble

When including a package using the `\usepackage` command that has a lot of options, are there:

1. Any restrictions on how the options can be split across multiple lines?
2. Any best practices for formatting the options across multiple lines?

#### Examples

```
% Example #1
\usepackage[letterpaper,
            left=1in,
            right=1in,
            top=1.5in,
            headheight=1in,
            headsep=.3in
]{geometry}

% Example #2
\usepackage[letterpaper,
            left=1in,
            right=1in,
            top=1.5in,
            headheight=1in,
            headsep=.3in]
{geometry}
```

Comment: Aside from not having any `\par` token (blank line) in the list of options, I don't think there is any particular restrictions. I usually use one line for each package option---the first option should be on the line following the one that contains `\usepackage`---so they can be commented in/out easily. Also, if I have many key=value pairs, I find that aligning the equal signs horizontally helps code readability.

Comment: `biblatex` sometimes reacts badly to spaces but only between certain options and I've yet to figure out the pattern. I've not tried it multiline, though.

Comment: @cfr TeX reports the newlines as spaces to the package so whatever happens newlines are the same as spaces (apart form two newlines being `\par`)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The standard processing runs the entire argument through `\zap@space` *before* processing the comma list, so all white space is ignored (except that a blank line would be turned into `\par` and generate an error before the processing starts.

However you show examples of geometry with a key=value list. You don't want to remove all white space in keyval parsing as the value might (in general) need spaces, Any package that has such a syntax has inserted its own option handler, so the answer in principle depends on the package used, however most will be using `keyval` or `xkeyval` or `l3keys` based systems in which case white space around the `,` and around the `=` will be ignored.

Answer (score 21):

Aside from not leaving any blank line within the list of options (equivalent to a `\par` token), I don't think there is any particular restriction.

My preferred formatting style for loading packages is shown below.

```
\usepackage[
    letterpaper,
    left        = 1in,
    right       = 1in,
    top         = 1.5in,
    headheight  = 1in,
    headsep     = .3in,
]{geometry}
```

Let me rationalise it, lest my answer be perceived as *primarily opinion-based*.

1. Each option should be on a line on its own, so it can be easily commented/uncommented without having to reformat the code or delete stuff. For this to work, the first option should be on a dedicated line (i.e. not on the same line as `\usepackage`), and the last option too should be on a dedicated line (i.e. not on the same line as the closing `]`).
2. Package options should be indented by one tab stop to make the options stand out.
3. If there are many `key=value` pairs, aligning the equal signs vertically usually makes the code much easier to read.

---

**Addendum (by Speravir)**

There’s a variation, where the commas are set in front of all, for people, who too easily tend to delete them at the end when changing a value:

```
\usepackage
[
    ,letterpaper
    ,left       = 1in
    ,right      = 1in
    ,top        = 1.5in
    ,headheight = 1in
    ,headsep    = .3in
]{geometry}
```

You could even have commas *before **and** after* each key-value pair, because empty strings are stripped, as well.

Comment: You could add the version, where the commas are in front of all. Some people like this more (me not), because they tend to delete them too easily otherwise.

Comment: @Speravir Meh, I don't really like that. Feel free to add is as an answer if you believe in that style, though.

Comment: Having the commas at front also easily allows commenting out options.

Comment: @MartinSchröder More than when you put them at the end? Why?

Comment: @MartinSchröder: Like Jubobs I do not understand. I comment out with commas at the end, too.

Comment: I'd never use the version with commas in front, it's ugly! ;-) The opening square bracket should better be next to `\usepackage`, in my opinion.

Comment: @egreg I agree about the comma-in-front version. The rationale behind having the square bracket on the next line is that you can comment out the whole optional argument in one fell swoop, without having to reformat or delete anything.

Comment: @Jubobs `\usepackage[]{package}` is equivalent to `\usepackage{package}`; I like better `\usepackage[`, new line, options, new line, `]{package}` that shows more clearly the start and end.

Comment: @egreg You've convinced me. `:)`